# Setting request body on JAX-RS 2.0 Client API With RestEasy

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

My first question on this community that has helped me so much already.

I'm using RestEasy and trying to do a **POST** request to a **REST** service sending a `JSON` object. The problem is that my `JSON` object keeps going as a request parameter and not in the request body, which is what I need.

Here is how I'm doing it.

```
Invocation inv = target.request().buildPost(Entity.json(shipment));

Response response = inv.invoke();
```

I've been looking for ours on how to put the JSON object into the request body but found nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unclear what are you asking. What request parameter did you receive? Give us full post request printout.

Comment: @andremoniy I've also been trying to get a print of the request but didn't figure out how. :S

Comment: May be you can use a tool such as TCPMon and capture the request. It will make your question more understandable.  https://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/tcpmontutorial.html#As_an_Explicit_Intermediate

Comment: When makes you say it's being sent as a parameter? The code looks fine to me.

Comment: how can I Fetch Request body in POST method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is resolved. There was a problem on the web service that was receiving my request.**

Thanks everyone for your comments!**